# Apache solr not sorting the solr results

Tags: solr

I have an issue with sorting in solr . I want to sort the solr results on the basis of a field which has “indexed” property set to “true” and is not multivalued. I am setting the sorting parameters using the “addSortField” method. Still I cannot see the solr results not sorted . Can you please guide me as to what needs to be done to solve this issue?

Comment: You can start by posting your schema and the code your are using so we can have a clearer idea about what is happening

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the field you are sorting on is analyzed (tokenized). This often makes the sort order pretty odd for strings. I often have a string type field without analysis (just lowercasefiltered) just for sorting, using a copyfield directive to fill it from your source field.